# visit all directories under version control

Tags: bash, shell, find, subversion

Is there a `find` incantation that would allow me to visit all directories under SVN version control? I am trying to use the `execdir` switch to add to the `svn:ignore` property in each one of these directories. Something like:

```
find . -type d -execdir svn propset svn:ignore -F <((svn propget svn:ignore; echo "new ignore pattern") | sort -u) .' \;
```

but I can't get to limit `find` to only SVN directories.

Comment: Is the problem that you have a forest of checkouts and only want to hit the checkouts, or that your checkouts have unversioned directories in them that you want to skip?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With older versions of `svn` where you had a `.svn` directory in each directory under revision control, you could do:

```
find . -name .svn -type d -prune -execdir bash -c '
  cd -P .. &&
    propset svn:ignore -F <(
      (svn propget svn:ignore; echo "new ignore pattern") | sort -u) .' bash {} \;
```

With the newer ones, where you only have one `.svn` and a sqlite3 db in there:

```
find . -path '*/.svn/wc.db' -execdir bash -c '
  cd -P .. &&
    sqlite3 .svn/wc.db "select local_relpath from NODES where kind == \"dir\"" |
      while IFS= read -r dir; do
        [ -d "$dir" ] &&
          propset svn:ignore -F <(
            (svn propget svn:ignore "$dir"; echo "new ignore pattern") | sort -u
          )  "$dir"
      done' bash {} \;
```

Comment: I believe my script below should work for both old and new SVN clients though I've only tried for 1.7.9

Comment: @MarcusJuniusBrutus, yes using `svn info` to check if a directory is under revision control is a more generic/saner approach (though you have issues with your shell syntax for which I add suggested an alternative). Mine above would be slightly more efficient in that it would avoid running a `svn info` command per directory.

Answer (score 1):

In the end, I used the following script.
The folder `.svn` has to be explicitly excluded as `svn info .svn` has an exit code of 0 and confuses the script.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
if [ $# -ne 1 ]
then
    echo "usage is $0 <new ignore pattern>"
else
    PATTERN=$1
    for d in $(find . ! -name ".svn" -type d)
    do
        svn info "$d" &> /dev/null
        if [ $? -eq 0 ]
        then
            svn -q propset svn:ignore -F <((svn propget svn:ignore ; echo "$PATTERN") | sort -u) "$d"
        fi
    done
fi
```

Comment: You may want to read the [BashPitfalls page from the Wooledge wiki](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls), especially [this](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29) and [this](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#cmd.3B_.28.28_.21_.24.3F_.29.29_.7C.7C_die)